# How To Reference Yaml File Relative to Launch File?

Tags: yaml, ros, launch

I have a launch file that is loading a yaml file:

```
<launch>
    <rosparam command="load file="filename.yaml" />
    <node pkg="my_package" type="my_package_node" name="my_package_node" />
</launch>
```

The filename.yaml file cannot be found unless I put a complete path: "/home/username/blah/blah/blah". Seeing as this launch file is used on multiple machines by different users and locations for the repository, I obviously cannot hard-code the path. So now what? How do I reference it relative to the location of the launch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best answer I could find myself was to use $(find package_name) as a starting point:

```
<launch>
    <rosparam command="load file="$(find package_name)/../../yamlFolder/filename.yaml" />
    <node pkg="my_package" type="my_package_node" name="my_package_node" />
</launch>
```

Seems kinda silly though. No reference to the path relative to the launch file itself? Would definitely like a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

we can set environment variable PWD for the specified node, eg we'd like to pass a rviz configuration file to rviz, the relative path can be like this:

```
<arg name="rviz_file" value="$(eval env('PWD')+'/config/showme.rviz')"/>
<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(arg rviz_file)" required="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If You are using ROS Packages, Launch Folders Are in the root folder of Package So `$(find package)` are actually one folder before your launch file

Answer (score 0):

If your yaml file is in a ROS package, then I think using the `find` substitution arg as you do in your answer is the cleanest route. If it's someplace else, I would suggest leveraging [environment variables](https://phoenixts.com/blog/environment-variables-in-linux/) with something like

```
<launch>
  <arg name="yaml_path" default="$(optenv YAML_PATH)"/>
  <arg     if="$(eval yaml_path == '')" name="yaml_file" value="$(env HOME)/some_folder/filename.yaml" />
  <arg unless="$(eval yaml_path == '')" name="yaml_file" value="$(arg yaml_path)/filename.yaml"/>
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg yaml_file)"/>
</launch>
```

This kind of gives the best of all worlds. If you've set `YAML_PATH` as an environment variable (e.g. `export YAML_PATH="$HOME/some_path"` from terminal or in your bashrc) then the path for `yaml_file` will use it. If not, `optenv` will evaluate to an empty string and the arg `yaml_file` will be set to some default path relative to your home folder. AND, if you have a user that doesn't want to mess with the environment variables at all, they can still pass in a path manually by calling it like

```
roslaunch my_launch_file.launch yaml_path:=/home/my_name/my_preferred_folder
```